# Unable to set HTTP header in asp.net core for the SPA files

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application

Looking to set HTTP headers when serving files that are part of a SPA application in ASP.Net core 2.2 when running from the command line directly (using Kestrel).

Following the instructions at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3147#issuecomment-435617378, I can't get the `StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse` events firing at all. Headers don't get set, and even breakpoints don't get triggered.

`Statup.Configure()` looks like this:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Hello", "World"); // Never triggers
        }
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Hello", "World"); // Never triggers
            }
        };

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the events don't fire when running the angular dev server. These lines were the culprit:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
}
```

Commenting it or changing the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable did the trick.